Identify movie about the NSA and the Echelon surveillance system
First of all sorry I've been trying to find this movie for quite some time, but no luck. I do remember some scenes from it.
It's about evaluation of Echelon accuracy in surveillance of phone calls.
A woman's phone call is captured by Echelon and red flagged as a national security threat. 
The NSA send a cleaner team to neutralize her. I cant remember how but she survives and tells the story to a friend. 
She and a couple of friends along with some retired and former NSA agents (i think) help her to prove the Echelon system can fail and can't recognize phone calls.
They go up a mountain and try to send another phone call like the original one captured by Echelon and she talk the same way again in an attempt to confuse Echelon and prove her innocence.
Finally it is shown the Echelon system is not as good as it should be.
End of story. 

Thanks for the detailed synopsis. Can you specify when and where you saw it?

In Ascolto (The Listening) - 2006
It sounds like it might be In Ascolto (The Listening) from 2006?
A retired NSA agent James Wagley, played by Michael Parks helps an Italian woman, Francesca, played by Maya Sansa who the NSA are trying to silence.
The technology called TUMBLEWEED in the film is very much ECHELON and ex agent Wagley attempts to counter the NSA from the Italian Alps.
Here is the trailer in case that rings any bells.




Special thanks man! Very Help full and   i think 99% is the same movie i seen  couple years ago specially its release time (2006)  .so it wasn't  Echelon in fact "TUMBLEWEED"   himmm....
